# Menu in Blank Activity

Tags: android

How can I add Menu option in Blank Activity? I've watched lots of videos to add menu option, they keep on showing menu folder in res, while I don't see menu folder in my project. How can I add menu option?

Comment: create the menu folder inside the res folder after that create the xml file in that folder for the menu option.

Comment: Just create the folder and add your menu.xml file. Look at the default empty `Activity` sample project (one of the options when you create a new project in Android Studio), it defines a sample menu item.

Answer (score 1):

After creating menu layout, You need to inflate your menu in the blank activity as well something like this

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
return true;
}
```

replace my_menu xml file with your ones

Comment: It Works. The XML file can be add in app > res > menu > my_menu.xml. Thanks